# Como usar una variable que guarda una caja de texto

Tags: python, tkinter

Buen día, Estoy intentado usar el texto capturado de una variable para luego usar ese texto capturado e igualarlo a otra variable. Pero al hacerlo me dice que la variable que captura el texto no esta definido. Solo he logrado imprimir el texto capturado en consola, Mas no eh podido utilizarlo como quiero.

Lo que busco lograr es que el texto ingresado en la variable, Puedo utilizarlo con otra variable. Por ejemplo. url = 'TEXTO' seria url = (Variable que guarda el texto)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import contextlib
import io



ventana = tkinter.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x500")
def send_data():
    username_data =username.get()
    password_data  =password.get()
    fullname_data =fullname.get()
username_label = Label(text="Ta cap", bg="#FFEEDD")
username_label.place(x=22, y=70)
password_label = Label(text="Mo", bg="#FFEEDD")
password_label.place(x=22, y=130)
fullname_label = Label(text="Lista", bg="#FFEEDD")
fullname_label.place(x=22, y=190)

username = StringVar()
password = StringVar()
fullname = StringVar()

username_entry = Entry(textvariable=username, width="70")
password_entry = Entry(textvariable=password, width="70")
fullname_entry = Entry(textvariable=fullname, width="70")

username_entry.place(x=22, y=100)
password_entry.place(x=22, y=160)
fullname_entry.place(x=22, y=220)

submit_btn = Button(ventana, text="Submit info", command=send_data, width="30", height="2", bg="#00CD63")
submit_btn.place(x=22, y=320)


urls = username_data
urls3 = password_data 
listaEp = fullname_data

page = requests.get(urls)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
page3 = requests.get(urls3)
soup3 = BeautifulSoup(page3.content, 'html.parser')
episodio = soup3.find('h1',class_='Title-epi mt-4')
img = soup3.find('meta',property='og:image')
opcion2 = soup3.find('iframe')



def embed():
    toplevel = tkinter.Toplevel(ventana)
    text = tkinter.Text(toplevel)
    text.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=True)

    file = io.StringIO()
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(file):
        algunos_prints()
        text.insert(tkinter.END, file.getvalue())

def algunos_prints():
    print(episodio.get_text("text").rsplit(' ',3)[0]+(" - Episodio ")+(episodio.get_text("text").rsplit(' ',3)[1]))
    print(listaEp)
boton = tkinter.Button(ventana, text="compila",command=embed)
boton.pack()
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que haces:

```
urls = username_data
urls3 = password_data 
listaEp = fullname_data
```

pero `username_data`, `password_data` y `fullname_data` se definen dentro de la función `send_data`. No existirán hasta que la función se llame, cuando el botón se pulse, pero además al ser variables locales ni siquiera podrás acceder a ellas desde fuera de la función.

Lo que tienes que hacer es meter toda la parte de requets y el scraping en la función `send_data`. Solo cuando el usuario agregue la información en las entradas de texto y pulse el botón se debe obtener la información de la página, ahora lo haces nada más iniciar la app.

```
def send_data():
    global episodio
    global listaEp
    urls =username.get()
    urls3  =password.get()
    listaEp =fullname.get()
    urls = username_data
    urls3 = password_data 
    listaEp = fullname_data

    page = requests.get(urls)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    page3 = requests.get(urls3)
    soup3 = BeautifulSoup(page3.content, 'html.parser')
    episodio = soup3.find('h1',class_='Title-epi mt-4')
    img = soup3.find('meta',property='og:image')
    opcion2 = soup3.find('iframe')
```

Ahora bien, no debería hacer ésto en el hilo principal, por su propia naturaleza la petición IO es bloqueante, mientras requests envía la petición, llega la respuesta y haces el scraping, el mainloop de la interfaz queda bloqueado y la interfaz deja de responder.

Lo adecuado es hacer todo lo anterior en un hilo hijo, por ejemplo:

```
import queue
import threading
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

import time

def get_data(urls, urls3, lista_ep, output_queue, success_event): 
    time.sleep(7)  # <<<<< Quita ésto, solo para simular un tiempo de espera largo
    try:      
        page = requests.get(urls)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        page3 = requests.get(urls3)
        soup3 = BeautifulSoup(page3.content, 'html.parser')
        episodio = soup3.find('h1', class_='Title-epi mt-4')
        img = soup3.find('meta', property='og:image')
        opcion2 = soup3.find('iframe')

        texto = (f"{episodio.get_text('text').rsplit(' ', 3)[0]}"
                  " - Episodio "
                  f"{episodio.get_text('text').rsplit(' ', 3)[1]}"
                  "\n"
                  f"{lista_ep}"
                  )
    except Exception:
        output_queue.put("Error en la obtención de datos")
    else:
        output_queue.put(texto)
    finally:
        success_event.set()


def show_data(data):
    success_event.clear()
    submit_btn.config(state="normal", text="Submit info")
    progress_bar.stop()
    progress_bar.place_forget()
    toplevel = tk.Toplevel(ventana)
    text = tk.Text(toplevel)
    text.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
    text.insert(tk.END, data)


def submit():
    submit_btn.config(state="disabled", text="Obteniendo datos...")
    progress_bar.place(x=400, y=335)
    progress_bar.start(10)
    threading.Thread(
        target=get_data,
        args=(
            ta_cap.get(),
            mo.get(),
            lista_ep.get(),
            data_queue,
            success_event
            )
        ).start()
    check_success_request()


def check_success_request():
    if not success_event.is_set():
        ventana.after(100, check_success_request)
    else:
        data = data_queue.get()
        show_data(data)

success_event = threading.Event()
data_queue = queue.Queue()

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry("600x500")

tk.Label(text="Ta cap", bg="#FFEEDD").place(x=22, y=70)
tk.Label(text="Mo", bg="#FFEEDD").place(x=22, y=130)
tk.Label(text="Lista", bg="#FFEEDD").place(x=22, y=190)

ta_cap = tk.StringVar(ventana)
mo = tk.StringVar(ventana)
lista_ep = tk.StringVar(ventana)

tk.Entry(textvariable=ta_cap, width="70").place(x=22, y=100)
tk.Entry(textvariable=mo, width="70").place(x=22, y=160)
tk.Entry(textvariable=lista_ep, width="70").place(x=22, y=220)

submit_btn = tk.Button(
    ventana, text="Submit info", command=submit,
    width="30", height="2", bg="#00CD63"
    )

submit_btn.place(x=22, y=320)

style = ttk.Style()
style.theme_use('clam')

style.configure("bar.Horizontal.TProgressbar",
                troughcolor="#000000",
                bordercolor="#00CD63",
                background="green",
                lightcolor="#00CD63",
                darkcolor="#00CD63")
progress_bar = ttk.Progressbar(
    ventana, mode='indeterminate', style="bar.Horizontal.TProgressbar"
    )

ventana.mainloop()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]